# Why is Google Apps Script not allowing me to call my range as a variable?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a basic question that I am hoping to have answer to further extend my knowledge of JavaScript/Google Apps Script. I'm very new to the language and to any type of programming. I feel like I'm getting a good understanding of the language in theory, but in practice I'm finding things a bit more difficult.

Here is a snippet of code I've written (it's only for practice):

```
let p = myTest(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
  function myTest(){
    let clickszz = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    clickszz = arguments[i];
    //let rng2 = sheet.getRange(i+2,1);
    sheet.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(clickszz);
    }
  }
```

You can see that I've commented out the rng2 variable. This is because when I try to write to the sheet using:

```
sheet.getRange(rng2).setValue(clickszz);
```

I'm getting the error: Exception: Range not found

Why am I unable to call the variable related to the range yet when I define the range directly within the method, it works as expected? I initially thought that it was because the range definition was not a variable literal, but I don't see why this would matter?

If it's important, sheet is a globally defined variable.

Thanks for you help.
Nicky

Comment: Hi Cooper, sheet is a globally defined variable written like this:
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

Comment: You should have included that in your code to have a [mcve]

Comment: My apologies although I did refer to it in the final line of my question. I will do that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `sheet.getRange()` returns you a range object rather than a range A1 notation

You have two options:

1.

```js
let rng2 = sheet.getRange(i+2,1);
rng2.setValue(clickszz);
```

2. 

```js
let rng2 = sheet.getRange(i+2,1).getA1Notation();
sheet.getRange(rng2).setValue(clickszz);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  function myTest(){
    let clickszz = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    clickszz = arguments[i];
    //let rng2 = sheet.getRange(i+2,1);
    sheet.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(clickszz);
    }
  }

let p = myTest(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

Active Sheet:

|  |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |

This also works for me:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  function myTest(){
    let clickszz = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    clickszz = arguments[i];
    let rng2 = sheet.getRange(i+2,1);
    rng2.setValue(clickszz);
    }
  }

let p = myTest(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear, it works for me too. I'm just trying to understand why the method is not allowing me to call the range when it's defined in a variable (i.e. the part that's commented out) and I have to define the range explicitly within the method itself?

Comment: My `sheet` is defined globally also... not within the function

Comment: If you remove // to stop let rng2 being a comment, are you able to get the final statement to work if it's written like this:
sheet.getRange(rng2).setValue(clickszz); 

If not, why does GAS not like the range being called via the rng2 variable?

Comment: Thank you Cooper. I only asked the question to try and understand why the language was behaving this way. Do you know why my method of declaring the range variable within the () didn't work? I really appreciate your help with this. Nicky